# Dradis 2.9 not installing on windows 8 OS 64 bit

Tags: ruby, rubygems

**Every time I install it it keep showing error in downloading the ruby 1.9.3 and then terminate**
Its been hours i am trying to install it on my windows, please someone tell me a way to install it
I have installed Ruby 1.9.3-p543 i don't know what to do next.
before terminating the installation it says to install sqlite3 manually and when i looked for it on internet it is just a gem file...how to install it.

Comment: I have installed ruby in C:/

Comment: and the dradis in both in C:/ and the default one

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have the same problem.